# HTTP Change variable and reload Sinatra

Tags: ruby, http, get, sinatra

I'm working with Sinatra and [a Hackernews API](https://github.com/tastejs/hacker-news-pwas/blob/master/docs/api.md) I've been struggling with pagination this API is not doing it with query parameters

So, for a site's info (page #1) the endpoint would be this
https://api.hnpwa.com/v0/news/1.json and for page #2 is this one https://api.hnpwa.com/v0/news/2.json

I want to send parameters from the .erb file to modify this but I haven't been able to

app.rb

```
helpers do
  def get_page(site, page)
    "https://api.hnpwa.com/v0/#{site}/#{page}.json"
  end
end

get '/' do
  @page = 1
  endpoint = get_page("news", @page)
  @stories = JSON.parse(HTTP.get(endpoint).to_s)
  erb :news
end
```

news.erb

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <% @stories.each_with_index do |story, index| %>
            <tr>
                <td class="post">
                    <div>
                        <a class="index" href="#"><%= index + 1 %>.</a>
                        <a href="<%= story['url'] %>" class="post-title"><%= story['title'] %></a>
                        <span><a class="url" href="<%= story['url'] %>">(<span><%= story['url'].nil? ? '' : story['url'].split('/')[2] %></span>)</a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-details">
                        <p><%= story['points'] %> points by <%= story['user'] %></p>
                        <p><%= time_since_in_words(story['time']) %> ago</p>
                        <p>| hide |</p>
                        <p><%= story['comments_count'] %> comments</p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>            
        <%end%>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a class="more" href=<% @page+=1%>>More</p>
```

I'm really new to Sinatra and Ruby so I have no idea what else to do. Help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece you are missing is that your action needs to receive some kind of parameter.

Currently you are always showing the first page:

```
get '/' do
  @page = 1
```

So in the path you have to communicate in some way to the action what page you want to show. For this you use parameters. There are two ways you can do this:

**With query parameters**

```
get '/' do
  # href should be something like "/?page=2"
  # set the page according to parameters or default to 
  @page = params['page'] || 1
  …
end
```

**With path params**

```
get '/:page' do
  # href should be something like "/2"
  @page = params['page']
  ...
end
```

Path params are not optional, so it does not work well for your use case, as you would need to have two routes, one for `/` and one for `/:page`. But this illustrates how you can use parameters.